# Change in Jsp/Html page in War file deployed on online web logic server without re-deployment?

Tags: java, html, jsp, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am working on online web logic server which is running on specific link.I have already deployed my Ear/War file on it but I want to make some changes in html/jsp page of deployed application. 
If I follow regular approach of deployment then it will take 20 minutes to deploy   it.

Is it possible to make changes without redeploying the application or is there any way to resolve this problem ?*

If possible share your explanation .

Comment: Did you do any research before asking? There are a lot of discussions about deploying content without full deploys or restarts I found just by searching on keywords from this question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the usual "delete"/"install" steps to redeploy an application, you can instead use the "update" button. This updates the deployment while the old version is still running. This works fine for simple webapps.

For more sophisticated solutions refer to the Redeployment Section of the Documentation (here is the 12.1.1 Documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24443/redeploy.htm#DEPGD288 )